# How to know which class is running at debuging

Tags: java, debugging, breakpoints

I have a huge project with many packages and many java classes, I know how to debug and program... but I have a really dummy question.

How can I know which class is actually running without breakpoints?

Comment: A class doesn't "run" -- There are potentially many different threads of execution which may, at any point in time, be executing within a particular method, or waiting on some condition.  It doesn't make sense to ask which class is running.

Comment: Are you wondering how you can profile a Java application to see which portions of your application are using the CPU more than others?